# retrieve role column value from database once logged in

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am using visual studio 2010 and a windows forms application in C#.
The application works properly I can login perfectly, and get the username logged in to the next form which is the menu form that opens once the login is successful.
Now my problem is I want to check whether the user logged in is Manager or Admin depending the value stored in the Role column in the database, so then I can disable some functionality for the Admin user.
Any ideas or help directing me to the right place please?
I hope my problem is clear

I have a table called tblUsers where I have the following fields:

```
userId
Username
Password
FirstName
LastName
Mobile
Landline
Address
Email
Role
```

//clsLoginCollection:

```
     public Boolean Login(clsLogin Login)
      {
        clsDataConduit logincheck = new clsDataConduit();
        logincheck.AddParameter("Username", Login.username);
        logincheck.AddParameter("Password", Login.password);

        logincheck.Execute("sproc_tblUser_Login");

        if (logincheck.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

//store procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sproc_tblUser_Login
@Username varchar(10),
@Password varchar(10)

AS

select Username, Password from tblUsers where Username = @Username AND Password = @Password
```

//clsLoginform:

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Boolean b = false;

        if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbUsername.Text)) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPassword.Text)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Cannot Be Blank.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            clsLoginCollection l = new clsLoginCollection();
            clsEncryption encrypt = new clsEncryption();// this class have the encryption method
            b = l.Login(new clsLogin(tbUsername.Text, encrypt.Encrypt(tbPassword.Text)));

            if (b == true)
            {
                MainMenu m = new MainMenu(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text);
                m.Show();
                this.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login Details", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
            }
        }
    }
```

//clsLogin in full

```
public class clsLogin
{
    private Int32 UserID;
    private string Username;
    private string Password;
    private string FirstName;
    private string LastName;
    private string Mobile;
    private string Landline;
    private string Address;
    private string Email;
    private string Role;

    public clsLogin()
    { }

    public clsLogin(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        this.username = UserName;
        this.Password = Password;
    }

    public clsLogin(string UserName, string Password, string FirstName, string LastName, string Mobile, string Landline, string Address, string Email, string Role)
    {
        this.username = UserName;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Mobile = Mobile;
        this.Landline = Landline;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Role = Role;
    }

    public Int32 userID
    {
        get { return UserID; }
        set { UserID = value; }
    }

    public string username
    {
        get {return Username;}
        set {Username = value;}
    }

    public string password
    {
        get {return Password;}
        set {Password = value;}
    }

    public string firstName
    {
        get { return FirstName; }
        set { FirstName = value; }
    }

    public string lastName
    {
        get { return LastName; }
        set { LastName = value; }
    }

    public string mobile
    {
        get { return Mobile; }
        set { Mobile = value; }
    }

    public string landline
    {
        get { return Landline; }
        set { Landline = value; }
    }

    public string address
    {
        get { return Address; }
        set { Address = value; }
    }

    public string email
    {
        get { return Email; }
        set { Email = value; }
    }

    public string role
    {
        get { return Role; }
        set { Role = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer to the question i have asked. I have used the query provided by rikki b

//clsLoginCollection (added a new method that returns the role)

```
public string CheckRole(clsLogin Rolecheck)
    {
        string Role;
        clsDataConduit dataconduit = new clsDataConduit();
        dataconduit.AddParameter("@Username", Rolecheck.username);
        dataconduit.AddParameter("@Password", Rolecheck.password);
        dataconduit.Execute("sproc_tblUsers_FilterByRole");

        Role = dataconduit.QueryResults.Rows[0]["Role"].ToString();

        return Role;
    }
```

and on my Login.cs class, i created a string variable to hold the result of this method

```
string role = ""
```

and underneath the

```
logindetails = l.Login(new clsLogin(tbUsername.Text, encrypt.Encrypt(tbPassword.Text)));
```

i have added this code

```
roleofuser =  l.CheckRole(new clsLogin(tbUsername.Text, encrypt.Encrypt(tbPassword.Text)));
```

so this "roleofuser" will return if the user is admin, manager, etc depending on the role and then with if/else statements iam able to redirect them to the correct form

Thanks
Just in case someone gets stuck in this particular problem

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT Role FROM tblUsers WHERE Username = @Username
```

Comment: I have got that sql query where i can login by checking the username and password, but now what i want to do is when am logged in is retrieve the value stored in the Role column to check whether the user is admin or manager and then redirect to admin form if is admin or manager form if it is manager

Iam using c# in visual studio 2010 and it is a windows forms application

Comment: ooops sowi didnt read ur query properly Rikki B
sowi
iam gonna try that in a bit

Comment: @user2267472 Yes your query checks the user and pass. You need another query to find the role for that user. Hopefully this one works for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help
I have still not managed to make it work
but ill work on it tomorw and post my results in here
thanks once again

Comment: Hi @Rikki B, i have finally sat today and made it work
i have used the query you provided but added password as well, just in case if two users have the same username but different roles

Comment: Congratultions. Glad you sloved it.